# Is it possible to run PyAutoGUI in headless mode?

Tags: python, headless, pyautogui

Is it possible to run PyAutoGUI in headless in windows 7 using Universal Termsrv.dll, creating multi seats?

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to use `PyAutoGUI` in the headless mode. All you need to do is provide a path to `PyAutoGUI` for virtual display. This process will run in the background and there will be no actual display. This method can also be used for using `PyAutoGUI` in `docker` as well.

**Code:**

```
import pyautogui
import os
from pyvirtualdisplay.display import Display
import Xlib.display


disp = Display(visible=True, size=(1920,1080), backend="xvfb", use_xauth=True)
disp.start()

pyautogui._pyautogui_x11._display = Xlib.display.Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
...
```

Comment: Can you expand the code to have an example? And with which Python version it works?

Comment: I have tested it with python==3.8 and pyAutoGUI==0.9.53. I was using selenium and docker. Can you please be exact about your requirement and provide additional information regarding what you want to do and I will try my best to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to click somewhere with mouse without cursor being moved, and I'm not sure if your answer is what I want. Like Selenium that clicks on an element, I want to click with `pyautogui` but in a Desktop application, like calculator or notepad.

Comment: Sorry, I have not specifically worked on this problem. However, you can use `pyautogui.moveTo(x-coord, y-coord)` and `pyautogui.click()` to move your cursor on a specific position and perform automatic click action without moving the cursor. You can find additional information here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html Let me know if you want to discuss more details.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to run `PyAutoGUI` in headless mode or on a remote desktop.

This feature is on the roadmap, but there is no timeline or resources dedicated to it.

**But, as a workaround**, you can use `xvfb-run` aka `Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server`:

```
xvfb-run python PyAutoGUI-script.py
```

Comment: Do you have source link? Is it still applicable in 2023?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of PyAutoGUI, and can confirm that in 2023 it still does not have a headless mode.

Comment: do PyautoGUI is ok to run with `xvfb-run` (aka `Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server`) ? I use it with Python Selenium + PyautoGUI in headless mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75913141/465183 I guess yes, as far as my mouse move in headless mode. Edited your POST, tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way:

```
xvfb-run python ./selenium-script.py
```

No need:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
display.stop()
```